# Vue.js how to bind object from array with index to use them attributes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I relativ new with vue.js and I try to bind objects from local array to an Bootstrap-Card. The target is to use the properties from the object in the Bootstrap-Card. In my case the index of the rigth object from the object array is the x and y coordinate from the table. So I have a width and a height, thats generate the table and after them, each of this cells becomes an object from the object array and the index is still the combinaction of the current width and height position.

My Code:

```
<template>
    <div class="content">
        <h1 class="p-4">Table Overview</h1>

        <div class="cards-list" v-for="row in height">

            <div class="card" v-for="col in width" v-bind='boxes[(col+""+row)]'>
                <div class="card_image">

                </div>
                <div class="card_title title-white">
                    <p>#Box {{col+""+row}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</template>

<script>

import Api from "../../src/api";

export default {
    name: "TableOverview",
    data() {
        return {
            height: 8,
            width: 12,
            boxes: [],
            settings: [],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        Api.get('/table-settings').then(response => {
            this.settings = response.data
            this.height = parseInt(this.settings['height'].value);
            this.width = parseInt(this.settings['width'].value);
        });

        Api.get('/boxes').then(respones => {
            this.boxes = respones.data
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

The Box-Object has the following properties:

```
"12": {
    "id": 2,
    "number": "12",
    "pos_height": 1,
    "pos_width": 2,
    "prio": 100
}
```

The index "12" is an combination between 'pos_height' and 'pos_width'.

My Target is loop all the boxes and at the and everybox is on the rigth position and i can use the propterties of each box/object in the Bootstrap-Card.

Can someone help me?

Comment: not a good idea for various reasons, instead just make an array or arrays with each object in it, and do a count on the loop to get the col length perhaps modulo, i.e if there is 12 items in the array its col-1, if there is 3 its col-4 etc, ordering and positioning is free then, all you need to do is ouptut a structured array

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks for your input, that's an interesting approach. Thanks!